# "line 0" in dotNET stack trace

Tags: c#, .net, stack-trace

I got an error report, where the top of the stack trace was similar to:

```
System.NullReferenceException: <...> at MyApplication.MyType.SomeMethod(String arg) in MyType.cs:line 0
```

The point is, that the line number is `0`. What could cause such stack-trace behavior?

Comment: This will help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/305244

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2827856/stack-trace-with-incorrect-line-number), it could be due to inlining. Have you got optimisations switched on?

Comment: Yes, optimization is turned on.