# C# Exception Line Number Is Always Zero (0)

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, .net-4.0, line-numbers

I published my project in debug mode and put both dll and pdb files in my server,
now i want to get exception line number using these codes :

```
   System.Diagnostics.StackTrace trace = new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace(ex, true);
   Response.Write("Line: " + trace.GetFrame(0).GetFileLineNumber());
```

but i don't know why line number of exception is always zero -> 0
how can i fix it?

Comment: This might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2827856/stack-trace-with-incorrect-line-number

Comment: Just use `ex.ToString()` instead of messing around with the stack trace and frames yourself.

Comment: hi, but ex.ToString() does not return line number of error!

Comment: dear dash, i saw that link - but problem still exists in release mode!

Comment: `ex.ToString()` returns the whole StackTrace, not only the line the exception has been thrown.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try

```
System.Diagnostics.StackTrace trace = new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace(ex, true);
var stackFrame = trace.GetFrame(trace.FrameCount - 1);
var lineNumber = stackFrame.GetFileLineNumber();
```

Comment: Doesn't `trace.GetFrame(trace.FrameCount - 1)` get the most ancestral frame (and therefore line) of code in your application's main method? (or just before the call to main in the system code?)

Comment: Didn't work in my case, still 0

Comment: @AmitaiWeil Agree, still returns zero... I'm also on this. I think it's depends on your architecture because for simple apps it's working.